# Why am I not able to grab the file selected in my <input type="file">?

Tags: php, html, ajax, wordpress, http

I'm developing a WordPress theme and I have a PHP function that is supposed to handle and asynchronous request that gives the server both JSON and an image. My form (for readability, stripped of a bunch of inner HTML) looks like

```
       <form method="POST" action="member-update"  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="member-form">
 9">
            <input type="text" name="fullname" value=""> 
            <input type="text" name="title" value="">
            <textarea rows="4" name="bio" form="member-form"></textarea> 
            <input type="text" name="sord" value=""> 
            <input type="file" name="pic">
            <input type="hidden" name="memberAction" value="" />
    </form>
```

and my JavaScript for making the AJAX request is

```
        jQuery('.member-update-button').click( function() {
            var parentForm = jQuery(this).closest('form');
            var postData = parentForm.serializeArray();
            jQuery.post( ajaxurl,
                        {'action': 'member_update', 'formStuff' : postData},
                        function(response) { alert('Got this from the server: ' + response); }
                       );
        });
```

and my PHP function that, through a WordPress hook, handles the request starts out like

```
function member_update ( )
{
    // there must be a more elegant way of getting those values out .... 
    $name = $_POST['formStuff'][0]['value'];
    $title = $_POST['formStuff'][1]['value'];
    $bio = $_POST['formStuff'][2]['value'];
    $sord = $_POST['formStuff'][3]['value'];


    $targetFileName = basename($_FILES['pic']['name']);
    $targetFileNameAndPath = 'assets/' . $targetFileName;
```

I'm getting values out of the `$_POST['formStuff']` array, but I am getting nothing for the `$_FILES['pic']['name']`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: just a thought, do you have a hook in your function file to deal with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an instance of `FormData`. 
Make following changes in your code.

Add id attribute in your html

```
<input type="file" name="pic" id="pic">
```

Changes in js code

```
jQuery('.member-update-button').click( function() {
   formdata = new FormData();
   formdata.append( 'action', 'member_update' );

   jQuery.each(jQuery('#pic')[0].files, function(i, file) {
       formdata.append('file_to_upload', file);
   });

   jQuery.post( ajaxurl, formdata,function(response) {
      alert('Got this from the server: ' + response); 
   });
});
```

Finally changes in php function

```
function member_update()
{
   $file = $_FILES['file_to_upload']['tmp_name'];
}
```